# In Android Studio, not able to add READ & WRITE permissions in java code to check permissions & can use only DYNAMIC_RECEIVER_NOT_EXPORTED_PERMISSION

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-permissions, android-studio-3.0

In Android Studio, I am unable to add READ_EXTERNL_STORAGE and WRITE_EXTERNL_STORAGE permissions in java code to check permissions and able to add only DYNAMIC_RECEIVER_NOT_EXPORTED_PERMISSION. Even I have been mentioned them in Manifest file as well. please check the attached screenshot.

[Java Code with DYNAMIC_RECEIVER_NOT_EXPORTED_PERMISSION](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lIxwE.jpg)

[Java Code(permissions) which I want to use](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8LUDY.jpg)

I have been already added these permissions in the Manifest File as well.

Anyone please help with this error, will be greatly appreciate.

I want to add READ_EXTERNL_STORAGE and WRITE_EXTERNL_STORAGE permission in my java code to check permissions while using the application in android studio. Please see attached screenshot

[Java Code(permissions) need to use](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mGLks.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors).

Answer (score 5):

There should be another `Manifest` class automatically generated by Android Studio for your project.

So in order to use original Android `Manifest` class, append `android.`:

```
android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
```

Comment: Thank you so much, issue has been resolved !

Comment: @KumarAbhishek then select this answer as the correct one